ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(), AssetId and fileName is Null
Im trying to upload a Image in backend using Appwrite. It requires attributes such as fileName,type,uri,fileSize. But when I capture the Image using camera using ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync() it contains attributes such as uri,type,size,etc. but the fileName and assetId is null. It works fine when I select Image from my gallery using ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync() as it contains data for all attributes. Here is my code
const takePhoto = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert('Sorry, we need camera permissions to make this work!');
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result,"photo taken in camera");

this is the console.log() output :
{"assets": [{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "fileName": null, "fileSize": 7301631, "height": 3025, "mimeType": "image/jpeg", "type": "image", "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BB32C249-451A-4087-A1A4-6D58724A0FA6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/@anonymous/shoplook-03082981-c4c4-42c7-96be-7cf4d4f49be6/ImagePicker/901109CD-75B2-4E58-9BBC-8E8921D9070A.jpg", "width": 3024}], "canceled": false} photo taken in camera

I tried to manually set the variable if photo is captured but this solution is not optimal and is only a temporary fix. So I need to know whether it is a problem for only Iphones or it is a general problem and is there any fix available.

I worked around a similar issue with ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync() by setting
allowsEditing property to false.
Could you try the same for ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()?
const takePhoto = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert('Sorry, we need camera permissions to make this work!');
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: false, //here
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result,"photo taken in camera");

